# Dispatch dictionary but pass different parameters to functions

Tags: python, design-patterns, asynchronous, event-handling, dispatch

I'm using the dispatch pattern in python like this....

```
    ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)

    eventType = (ok[9][1])
    nName = (ok[10][1])
    hName = (ok[11][1])
    cName = (ok[12][1])

    def newChannel(cName):
        queue = j.queue(cName)
        r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriberCreateChanTable, subscriberSortScenes])

    def newNetwork(hName):
        queue = j.queue(hName)
        r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriber1a])

    def loginError(nName):
        pass

    action = {'newChannel': newChannel,
             'newNetwork': newNetwork , 'loginError': loginError}

    handler = action.get(eventType)
    handler(cname)
```

How do I pass different function parameters to the mapped function
so if eventType = "newChannel", then newChannel function will get called with cname,
but if eventType = "newNetwork", how do i call it with hname variable instead.

just call handler(hname)?

```
    handler(hname)
    handler(cname)
    handler(nName)
```

?

Comment: How about you just create a tuple (hName, cName, nName). And pass the tupple to the handler function (newChannel, newNetwork, ...). In the handler function just use the correct indexes to refer to the argument. So, you'd use input[1] in newChannel and input[0] in newNetwork.

Comment: what would you say is diff btw doing this vs the answer below... pros/cons?

Comment: @sivon: I think Bruno's solution is way better than mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use a lambda or partial or just store the params in the dict too:

```
action = {'newChannel': (newChannel, hname),
             'newNetwork': (newNetwork, cname) , 'loginError': (loginError, nName)}

handler, param = action.get(eventType)
handler(param)
```

Now it still means you have to build `action` on each request. Another solution that avoids this is to write "getter" for the params and store (handler, getter) pairs:

```
def newChannel(cName):
    queue = j.queue(cName)
    r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriberCreateChanTable, subscriberSortScenes])

def newNetwork(hName):
    queue = j.queue(hName)
    r = queue.add_subscribers(*[subscriber1a])

def loginError(nName):
    pass

def hName(ok):
    return ok[11][1]

def cName(ok):
    return ok[12][1]

def nName(ok):
    return ok[10][1]

def eventType(ok):
    return ok[9][1]


action = {
    'newChannel': (newChannel, cName),
    'newNetwork': (newNetwork, hName),
    'loginError': (loginError, nName)
     }


ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)
handler, getter = action.get(eventType(ok))
handler(getter(ok))
```

The same example using lambdas:

```
action = {
    'newChannel': lambda ok: newChannel(cName(ok)),
    'newNetwork': lambda ok: newNetwork(hName(ok)),
    'loginError': lambda ok: loginError(nName(ok))
     }

ok = parse_qsl(urlparse(u).query, keep_blank_values=True)

handler = action.get(eventType(ok))
handler(ok)
```

In this case it just makes for less explicit code and useless overhead IMHO, but sometimes a lambda-based solution let you capture some additional context that's not available at the point you define your other functions.

Or you could have done the param parsing in the lambdas themselves, ie :

```
action = {
    'newChannel': lambda ok: newChannel(ok[12][1]),
    'newNetwork': lambda ok: newNetwork(ok[11][1]),
    'loginError': lambda ok: loginError(ok[10][1])
     }
```

but that's still less explicit (and less testable) than using plain functions.

Comment: can you give an example of the other suggestions, if you have it readily available? and speak more on the benefits of them...

Comment: where's the parsing of the query string in the lambda example? thats abstracted too..

Comment: ok ok i get it !!, the lambdas makes the calls and the mappings alil cleaner

Comment: so more explict is better for testing in your experience... i'm like lost in space when it comes to integrating testing into my design/implementation...what resources would you suggest?

Comment: More explicit is more readable, and obviously it's easiest to test the `cName`, `hName` and `nName` methods than their inlined versions in the last example.

Comment: wrt/ testing, the best way to have testable code is to write the tests before the code (one test / one piece of code at at time). It's also the best way to make sure you actually write tests ;)

Comment: if you have the time can give an example using my code above...how would i have written a test piece? it's always best for me to learn something very foreign directly from a human.

Comment: im getting this error .... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unifiedLogListener.py", line 129, in <module>
    test = handler, getter  = action.get(eventType(ok))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable... but eventType function prints out the correct value

Comment: `__dict__.get` returns `None` when the key is not found. If you're not _sure_ you'll have a handler for `eventType(ok)`, you'd better use direct key access (ie `action[whatever]` and wrap it in a try/except block, or provide a default generic (handler, getter) pair as a default value to `action.get`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44158/discussion-between-sirvon-and-bruno-desthuilliers)

Comment: everything is good, thank you for the guidance and the pointers.