# how to pass multiple function parameters in dictionary?

Tags: python, dispatch

I have this pattern already in use, 
but I'm trying now to pass multiple parameters to the function
should I just add another parameter or is there another syntactical piece I'm
missing?

```
    def newChannel(hname, cname):
        pass

    action = {'newChannel': (newChannel, hname),
         'newNetwork': (newNetwork, cname) , 'loginError': (loginError, nName)}

    handler, param = action.get(eventType)
    handler(param)
```

How can i pass multiple params though?
like such......

```
    action = { 'newChannel': (newChannel, hname, cname) }
```

is that correct?

EDIT:
Would this fly?

```
    action = {'newChannelQueueCreated': (newChannelQueueCreated, (channelName, timestamp)), 'login':    
    (login, networkName), 'pushSceneToChannel': (pushSceneToChannel, channelName),  
    'channelRemovedFromNetwork': (channelRemovedFromNetwork, (channelName, timestamp))}
     print ok 
     handler, getter  = action.get(eventType(ok))
     handler(*getter(ok))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a tuple?

```
action = {'newChannel': (newChannel, (hname, cname)),
          'newNetwork': (newNetwork, (cname,)),
          'loginError': (loginError, (nName,))}

handler, params = action.get(eventType)
handler(*params)
```

Comment: exactly why not! perfect.

Comment: action = {'newChannelQueueCreated': (newChannelQueueCreated, channelName), 'login': (login, networkName), 'pushSceneToChannel': (pushSceneToChannel, channelName), 'channelRemovedFromNetwork': (channelRemovedFromNetwork, (channelName, timestamp))}
print ok 
handler, getter  = action.get(eventType(ok))
handler(*getter(ok))

Comment: please see above edit ... would that fly b/c im unfamiliar with the (*params)

Comment: I don't understand what that is supposed to be doing. The second value, which you've assigned to `getter`, seems to vary between a single value or a tuple - but either way you can't call it with `getter(ok)`, I don't understand what you are trying to do there.

Comment: refer to this eariler question please....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838887/dispatch-dictionary-but-pass-different-parameters-to-functions

Comment: yeah it was only accepting a single parameter but i'm trying to understand how to allow multiple parameters now. i'm pulling the parameters from a query string then using that value as a parameter.